# How to property update bootstrap autocomplete source after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently implementing the autocomplete bootstrap control from here. I only want to populate the source when characters are more than 2. I'm wondering how do I populate my type ahead source after a successful ajax call.

https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead.

```
var $input = $(".typeahead");
$input.keyup(function () {
    var count = $input[0].value.length;
    if (count >= 3) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/Home/GetProducts',
            data: {
                characters: $input[0].value
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $input.typeahead({
                    source: response,
                    autoSelect: true
                });                    
            }
        });
    }        
});
```

When I put a breakpoint at response, this is the result

[image]

So my ajax query works, but the type ahead doesn't populate with the results and aren't searchable.

Comment: Is the title of your question correct?

Comment: You could call `destroy` on it and then recreate it with the new dataset.